# onFocus not working with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, glow

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/18/)'s the fiddle. I'm trying to make the textbox glow `0 0 30px #96f226` using onFocus in the input tag, but you know when you click on a textbox and the border changes? That's when I want it to glow. The JS follows everything I have know, but it doesn't work.

JS (just for the problem):

```
function input() {
    var x = document.getElementById('input');
    x.style.box-shadow = '0 0 30px #96f226';
}
```

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp - to set the CSS property via JS the property is element.style.boxShadow - not box-shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `box-shadow` to `boxShadow`. try this code for toggling focus

```
function inputfocus(x) {
    x.style.boxShadow = '0 0 30px #96f226';
}
function inputblur(x) {
    x.style.boxShadow = 'none';
}

<input type="text" onFocus="inputfocus(this)" onblur="inputblur(this)">
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kashimu/UbR8E/2)

**CSS**

```
#input:focus{
   box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px #96f226;
}
```